# AWS OpenSearch-1.3.2 error: 'Unknown aggregation type [multi_terms] did you mean [rare_terms]'

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am facing error like below while executing multi_terms search in OpenSearch.

```
“Unknown aggregation type [multi_terms] did you mean [rare_terms]?”
```

I had followed the query syntax in https://opensearch.org/docs/1.3/aggregations/bucket/multi-terms.

The above documentation is for *1.3* release, and I am using *1.3.2* version provided by AWS-OpenSearch.

I found multiple articles over the web like https://github.com/opensearch-project/OpenSearch/issues/4404, which suggests that it was released in '2.1.x' version.
But what about 1.3.x versions?

If it is not supported, is there any alternative for aggregating on multiple terms in this version?

Thanks